# Why is the type of (-i), where i is unsigned int, still unsigned int?

Tags: c++, c, clang

```
int main() {
    unsigned int i = 1;
    typeof(-i) j = -i;
}
```

When I look into the type of `j` in gdb, it shows it to be of type `unsigned int`. Why didn't the type move to the corresponding signed type? Is there a reason behind choosing this behavior? I find if the type would have converted to corresponding signed type more intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negation of an unsigned type doesn't produce a signed, negative value, because unsigned negation is meaningful and useful.

Firstly, for an given unsigned value `a` there is an unsigned value `b` such that `a + b == 0`. It makes sense to identify `b` as `-a`, and *vice versa*: a kind of additive inverse operation under the type's modulo arithmetic.

Unsigned arithmetic can emulate two's complement; in that situation, the negation serves as the two's complement operator: it "flips all the bits and adds one". For instance, `-0x1U` is `0xFF...FFU`.

Answer (score 5):

The unary negation operator `-` doesn't alter the type of its argument, other than applying integer promotions.  Section 6.5.3.3p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states:

> The result of the unary `-` operator is the negative of its (promoted)
>   operand. The integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the
>   result has the promoted type

The details of integer promotions are detailed in section 6.3.1.1p2:

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or
>   `unsigned int` may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than `int` or `unsigned int`) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to
>     the rank of `int` and `unsigned int`.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as
>   restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to
>   an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are
>   called the *integer promotions*. All other types are unchanged by the
>   integer promotions.

The type of `i` is `unsigned int` which according to the above passage is not subject to integer promotions (indeed, it is a destination type of integer promotions).  Therefore no promotion is performed and the type of `-i` is the same as the type of `i`.

Comment: Also, since the value of `i` is still an unsigned type after integer promotions (`unsigned int` in this case), the _mathematical_ negative of the value `i` will be converted to the unsigned type by repeatedly adding one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the unsigned type until the value is in the range of the unsigned type as per 6.3.1.3p2 (although in this case, that is effectively just performing a 2's complement operation on the unsigned typed value).

Comment: All true but the question asks _why_.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica: Yes, I do wish more respondents would pay attention to the question asked (or intended) instead of mechanically writing a technical response.